# Creating C structures with arrays of fixed size in NodeJs

Tags: python, node.js, struct

I'm trying to convert a Python code to Node and the Python code looks like this:

```
import ctypes

class c_structure(ctypes.Structure):
    class _u(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ('att1', ctypes.c_uint32),
            ('att2', ctypes.c_char * 200),
        ]
```

So far I've got this:

```
const ref = require('ref');
const StructType = require('ref-struct');
const ArrayType = require('ref-array')

const charArray = ArrayType(ref.types.uint8);

const c_structure = StructType({
    att1: ref.types.uint32,
    att2: charArray,
});
```

The problem is that I cannot specify the size of the array in the Node code (at least I could not find how). Can someone please help me translate the Python code to Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had almost got it:

```js
const charArray = ArrayType(ref.types.uint8, 200);
```